# Android application with infinite navigation

Tags: android

I have an application that support infinite navigation. I have developed the app using fragment. When the back stack size grows to 15 i have to remove the first 5 five fragment ie 0-4. How can i achieve this .

I found following methods

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry fifth = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(4);
manager.popBackStack(fifth.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

i tried above code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the backstack is aptly named and operates as such, this functionality is not possible.

You likely *could* hack something together that may do what you're asking, but I would never suggest anyone actually implements it.

For the curious, this is what I'm thinking:

***[WARN] Terrible Hack to Follow***

---

I think the only way you could achieve this functionality would be to use `getBackStackEntryAt(int index)` inside a loop from 5 to `getBackStackEntryCount()`, adding each `BackStackEntry` to a list of some sort.

Once you've got that list, you could wipe out the entirety of the backstack, effectively eliminating the items within the range that you've requested. Iterate through the `List<BackStackEntry>`, run a `getName()` on each to lookup the fragment you've added by that name.

With those names, you could lookup which of your fragments match, then re-add all of those to the backstack.

(This of course assumes that you've been adding fragments with a *unique name*.)

Depending how long your stack is, the end result would likely be a horrendous lag while your device figures all of this out.

---

I have not tried this myself and would not suggest anyone try this for an app that would ever be used by anyone.

...Unless you want, I'm not the police.